# Excel subtract duration from duration

Tags: excel, time

Not sure if i can post this question here, but taking chance.
I tried finding out online resources for these.
Every one suggested to have for columns like

- in time
- lunch out time
- lunch back time
- Time out

I don't want to do that, I want to do it in 3 columns.

I am creating a Excel time-sheet template

- In Time

  - Cell A1: **9:05 AM** (Format Time: 1:30 PM)
- Out Time

  - Cell B1:
    **6:15 PM** (Format Time: 1:30 PM)
- Break Duration

  - Cell C1: **0:30 h:mm**
    (Format Custom h:mm *h:mm*)

To get total Duration after the Break I need to calculate **(B1-A1) - C1**

**B1-A1** works perfect, but if I try to exclude Break duration then I get problem.

I am using Excel 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your result cell is in the *h:mm* format.

Also, since you are dealing with time sheets, I would recommend using *[h]:mm* format for all of your "Total" cells which will accumulate hours greater than 24 hours (otherwise it will start over at 0; 40 hours will look like only 16).

Nothing that you have shared so far should be an issue:

[image]

Columns A and B are in the *h:mm AM/PM* format
Column C, D, and E are in the *[h]:mm* format

Perhaps you could make sure that the Workbook is calculating automatically, or else it will appear that the values don't add up.

Comment: All A1, B1 and C1 are in h:mm;@ and ComputedCell is in [h]:mm:ss still it works only for (B1-A1) but not for (B1-A1)-C1    A1=9:05, B1=18:15 C1=0:30

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: a big line of these ##########

Comment: The hashes either mean that your column is too small, or you have encountered a negative date. Make sure that if there is a date attached to your time, it is the same date.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. Lunch break cell was having some problem I deleted the value and entered then it worked.